# Property file from classpath is not getting picked java spring

Tags: java, spring

I am accessing property file from class path in eclipse using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">     
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath :database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However while creating jar using maven I am excluding the property file.

I then place jar in base installation folder and property file in properties folder.

Now when I execute the jar using

```
java -cp ../properties/* abc.jar
```

it throws database.properties file cannot be found while initializing xml error.

Comment: I'm not sure that `classpath :` should be there?

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/*.properties" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">     
<property name="location">
    <value>${app.jdbc.username}</value>
    <value>${app.jdbc.password}</value>
</property>
</bean>
```